# Automate Browser Searching

Tags: windows, google-chrome, automation

I need to search a number of websites for different values. Can anyone think of a way to have chrome:

1. Open a specific site
2. Use the search function on that site to search for "X"
3. Take a screenshot/output that result
4. Move on to the next site and do the same steps.
5. Once completed, start the process again for a new value "X+1"

Thanks!

Comment: Combine curl and grep instead ?

Comment: If you need to use a browser, you can use a webdriver-based solution (e.g. selenium).